# 特定のフォルダの中にあるファイルの拡張子を一気に書き換えたい。

Tags: python

今まで`.dat`で何も考えずファイルを作って来たのですが、
今回、一部の拡張子を一気に`.gui`という形に変えたいと
考えています。
  1.os.listdir()でファイルの名前を全てゲット。
　2.endswith(".dat")あるいは、正規表現にマッチするものを、
　  ".gui"に書き換える。
しらみつぶしにかえようとすると、
ファイルが使えなくなるという注意書きが出ましたが、
問題なく使えるようなので、この際一気に書き換えられる
手段を知りたいと思いました。

```
import os
current = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"widgets_data")
listdir = os.listdir(current)
import re
dat_to_gui = re.compile(".*\.gui")

for i in listdir:
    if i.endswith(".dat"):
        new = i.replace(".dat",".gui")
        listdir.remove(i)
        listdir.append(new)
```

これだと、listdir関数の中は確かに、
.gui拡張子になるのですが、元のファイルの中身は
全く変わっていません。

ピリオドは拡張子部分にしかないので、
他の部分が書き換わることはないと考えてよいと
思います。ファイルの内容を変えないように、
ファイルの名前だけを書き換えられる方法を
教えていただきたい。
　なんか簡単な気がするけど、そうでもない
気も致しますが、お願いします。

Comment: WindowsでもMacでもLinuxでも標準のコマンドで簡単にできる作業ですが、pythonでやる必要があるのでしょうか？ 提示されているコードはメモリ上のファイル名リストを編集しているだけで、ファイルのリネームは行っていません。

Comment: はい。だいたい想定通りのお答えだったです。それではそういうご回答をお待ちしております。私一番得意なのパソコンを差しおいて今のところ`PySide`なもので、すいません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225735/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory

にたくさん回答がありました。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917798/1979953
を要件の拡張子に合うようにしたものが下記です。（リンク先にも書いてありますが、カレントディレクトリのみです）

```
import os
[os.rename(f, f.replace('.dat', '.gui')) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

補足：試してないですが
https://stackoverflow.com/a/227125/1979953
のがやれることは多そうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pythonで答えていただいて少し得をした気がします。最近私横着になってますが今回を機にできるだけ調べて聞きたいと思います。

Comment: 意外と本家サイトにあるのに検索できるようになると強いと思いますよ。